# Using coordinator layout with recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i make recycler view move along with viewpager
The recycler view is not moving with the view pager . I have used a coordinator layout with a collapsing toolbar layout but still recycler view is srolling independently and not with the viewpager. The view pager is collapsing but only in that specific area..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:id="@+id/slider_pager">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:id="@+id/list_hotels"
                android:background="@color/back1">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please help me move them up and down together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app bar/toolbar part looks okay.  However, you have a `RecyclerView` wrapped in a `NestedScrollView` and that is unnecessary.

Remove the `NestedScrollView` entirely and declare your `RecyclerView` like this:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:id="@+id/list_hotels"
            android:background="@color/back1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

If you still have problems, update your question with the new XML layout.

Comment: now both are going together but while sliding up it stops at the first item of recycler view i.e on full scrolling upwards the view automatically stops at the first element of recycler view and on further scrolling the viewpager appears. What can i do to maintain a smooth flow such that viewpager comes automatically..

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are saying, you want the `ViewPager` to appear as soon as you start swiping down.  Change `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` on your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`.